# How to add dependencies to my makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Hi say I have a program called "myProg", it doesn't take any argument but
I would like to add the dependancy to run ONLY when file1 is newer than the
outfile1 (outfile1 is produced the myProg)

The makefile I have is like the following

```
out : file1 outfile1
    myProg
```

But it seems it always runs myProg to generate a new outfile1 no matter what.
Where am I missing? Do I have to involve the `$<` and `$@` in the command line in order
to make the dependency to work? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out. its just that the outfile1 needs to be the "out" then it will just work.

Comment: You should post the fixed snippet and accept this answer.